# Docusign api Connect

Tags: php, connection, docusignapi

I am experiencing connection problems to demo API
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi 
To connect to API I am using the code provided below. It works well for my colleague from US, but when I try to connect from Lithuania there is zero response. 
Could it be there any location restrictions, or am I missing something? 
Should it be some specifics in fire wall (I am under NAT)?
 Does my local php/http server needs some specific configuration?

```
$email = "some email @ fsdfdsf";
$integratorKey = "TEST-xxxxxxxxxxx";
$password = "some password";

$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information?include_account_id_guid=true";
$header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if($status==200){
    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
    print_r(json_encode($response['loginAccounts'][0]));
}else{
    print_r($json_response);
}
```

Comment: It is certainly possible that your firewall is preventing access. What HTTP error are you receiving? FYI the DocuSign IP ranges (if you need to update your FW rules) is available at: https://trust.docusign.com/en-us/trust-certifications/ip-ranges/

Comment: I was able to get a login responce via REST client. But how to get responce via PHP, I am willing to use php docusign client v2

Comment: I am receiving an error while loging in via API and in unittest  is the same error. There is part of error message : <br>There was 1 error:

1) UnitTests::testLogin
DocuSign\eSign\ApiException: API call to https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information timed out: a:26:{s:3:"url";s:54:"https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";s:12:"content_type";N;s:9:"http_code";i:0;s:1
..............
:"162.248.186.25";s:8:"certinfo";a:0:{}s:12:"prim
ary_port";i:443;s:8:"local_ip";s:13:"192.168.1.126";s:10:"local_port";i:38635;}
C:\xampp\htdocs\localbits\ds\docusign\src\ApiClient.php:233

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a what was stopping to work a source code above.
On my local server ssl was not signed. 
So simple and only in test environment quick fix could be to turn off ssl checking on curl:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

or get a signed ssl sertificate.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it, I added `$config->setSSLVerification(false);` tu turn off ssl verification

```
 $username = "marko@XXX.com";
$password = "XXX";
$integrator_key = "some_key";     

// change to production before going live
//https://www.docusign.net/restapi
//https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/GettingStarted/REST%20API%20Version.htm
$host = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi";

 // create a new DocuSign configuration and assign host and header(s)
$config = new \DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
$config->setHost($host);
$config->setSSLVerification(false);
$config->addDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", "{\"Username\":\"" . $username . "\",\"Password\":\"" . $password . "\",\"IntegratorKey\":\"" . $integrator_key . "\"}");
// instantiate a new docusign api client
$apiClient = new \DocuSign\eSign\ApiClient($config);
```

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign does not implement any location restrictions for API clients.

You can check that your firewall is allowing connections to DocuSign by trying to use the service from your web browser. Try [demo.docusign.net](https://demo.docusign.net)

You can also use your browser to [directly access a method in the API server that provides information on the API service points.](https://www.docusign.net/restapi/help)

If it works then you know the problem is in your API code.
If so, first try one of the [API recipes](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes).

If you can't access the web service then check your firewall settings.

Comment: I found baseUrl, but I cannot access it , do I need to make a request https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/XXX/envelopes/acdf93aa-f1f1-4ba0-a6f6-8883c6d20251/documents/1

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve documents from DocuSign's PHP library?

Comment: You can use the PHP SDK's method that implements [this call](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Document%20from%20Envelope.htm)